# How to force Scanner.next() to output a value?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm currently working on a Java program, which brings a basic config File Editor running over command line.
I have 1 Problem... Some entries have to be valid outputs.
I tried using

```
while(!scanner.hasNext()){
    System.err.println("Invalid Value");
}
String str = scanner.next();
```

In my opinion this should work, because every time scanner.hasNext(); is called the program should pause until something is entered in the console.
But when I run the program (entering invalid values) it just keeps looping the loop.
Am I doing something wrong or is this just a Bug?
Thanks for any Help!

Comment: Are you saying that you get flooded with "Invalid Value" infinitely times because it's in the while-loop?

Comment: if `scanner.hasNext()` is returning false, it means you have reached the end of the stream and calling it more times won't help.

Comment: @Gendarme basically yes

Comment: @PeterLawrey any workarounds/solutions?

Comment: Workaround? Don't use a loop, since it won't help anyway.

Comment: What is a work around for running out of input?  Input a longer file perhaps...

Comment: @PeterLawrey What I'm trying to achieve, is to allow the user to re-enter his options instead of throwing an error and just exiting the program

Comment: @RoiEX that is what hasNext() does, it will block until something is entered or the stream is terminated. Note: the console is line buffered so entering a word without hitting enter won't do anything.

Comment: If you want to request another input until it is valid, then please search for something like "loop until valid input", because there are a lot of question like this.

Comment: Why don't you just have `while(true)` and an if-else inside the loop?

Comment: @Gendarme I tried... same result

Comment: @Tom Thanks, I found some solutions for this... one of those will probably be what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness here is a quick solution that employs the `while (true)`-approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = null;
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Please enter SOME INFORMATION:");
            if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                input = scanner.nextLine();
                if (inputIsSane(input)) break;
                System.out.println("Your input is malformed. Please try again.");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Got valid input. Input was: " + input);
    // continue with the rest of your program here
}

private static boolean inputIsSane(String input) {
    // replace with your actual validation routine
    return input.equals("let me pass");
}
```